# QtQuick menu Instantiator: notify about changed rows

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have menu items model and [Instantiator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qml-qtqml2-instantiator.html) for it.

```
Menu {
    id: backContextMenu
    Instantiator {
        model: backModel
        MenuItem {
            text: model.text
        }
        onObjectAdded: {
            console.log("QML: object added: " + object.text + ", index= " + index);
            backContextMenu.insertItem(index,object)
        }
        onObjectRemoved: {
            backContextMenu.removeItem(object)
            console.log("QML: object removed: " + object.text);
        }
    }
}
```

When I add some items to model at index 0 signal `objectAdded` is emitted with new MenuItem and `index=0` as expected. But if I want to drop some items from model (for example, I have `["a";"b";"c";"d"]` in model and want to remove "a" and "b") menu items are dropped from another side ("c" and "d" are dropped, "a" and "b" are still alive). After some hacking I found workaround: If I remove `n` items from the beginning of model I should write

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), _items.count()-n, _items.count()-1);
```

instead of

```
beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, n-1);
```

Any ideas why items are removed from another side? I have [demo](https://github.com/Kakadu/qtquick_test_instantiator) for you.